# How do I combine these specific .htaccess rules sets?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Combining htaccess commands:

Hi everyone! I am trying to combine sets of rules, but, at least according to [this tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/)  only one set will execute no matter how I seem to combine them. I have tried reading other posts here first, but haven't had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Rule set 1:

```
# Redirect URLs ending with "/index.html" to the corresponding URL without "index.html"
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Rules set 2:

```
# Redirect to HTTPS and www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash and question mark
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

I have tried switching orders and nothing seems to work.

Here's what I think should be working, but doesn't.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect URLs ending with "/index.html" to the corresponding URL without "index.html"
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# Redirect to HTTPS and www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Remove trailing slash and question mark
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+)\? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

I would like to have the following results:

```
http://example.com/baking/index.html
```

becomes

```
https://www.example.com/baking
```

Comment: Why would you need to use rewriting for that at all? Why not simply set `index.html` as a `DirectoryIndex` and that's it?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]` - you would be adding a trailing slash here, but according to your description, you don't want that?